# Facebook callback error

Tags: android, facebook

i'm new on android development, got some problems on trying to implement a facebook login with FacebookSDK and didn't find what is needed to resolve this... When i click on the button, the callback returns the following error: **SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1675030 [message]: Error performing query. [extra]: Errors while executing operation "ProxyAuthAppLoginStartQuery": At Query.proxy_auth_app_login_start: Failed to resolve field.** Then a loading appears and nothing happens.

Here is the Activity code:

```
private static final String TAG_CANCEL = "1";
private static final String TAG_ERROR = "2";
public static CallbackManager callbackManager;
private LoginButton loginButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Call private method
            onFblogin();
        }
    });
}

private void onFblogin() {
    // Set permissions
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email", "user_photos", "public_profile"));
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    System.out.println("Success");
                    GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {
                                    if (response.getError() != null) {
                                        // handle error
                                        System.out.println("ERROR");
                                    } else {
                                        System.out.println("Success");
                                        try {

                                            String jsonresult = String.valueOf(json);
                                            System.out.println("JSON Result" + jsonresult);

                                            String str_email = json.getString("email");
                                            String str_id = json.getString("id");
                                            String str_firstname = json.getString("first_name");
                                            String str_lastname = json.getString("last_name");

                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }).executeAsync();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.d(TAG_CANCEL, "On cancel");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                    Log.d(TAG_ERROR, error.toString());
                }
            });
}


private void goMainScreen() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | 
 Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
 data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

and the Manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.breno.tcc">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" 
    android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    </application>

     </manifest>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, i was setting the app id with the wrong value.